# Node.js formidable rename uploaded file

Tags: node.js, fs, formidable

Trying to finish the book "The Node beginner book" and the last thing I need is to implement modifying a request handler, which shows an image, renamed after a user has uploaded it, I'm using node-formidable and the fs module.

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    formidable = require("formidable");
function upload (resp, req) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (error, fields, files) {
        /* This is the part that doesn't work on Windows */
        fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png", function (error) {
            if (error) {
                fs.unlink("/tmp/test.png");
                fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png");
            }
        });
        resp.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        resp.write("Received image:<br/>");
        resp.write("<img src=/show />");
        resp.end();
        });
}

function show (resp) {
    fs.readFile("./tmp/test.png", "binary", function (error, file) {
        if (error) {
            resp.writeHead(500, {"Content-type":"text/plain"});
            resp.write(error + "\n");
            resp.end();
        } else {
            resp.writeHead(200, {"Content-type":"image/png"});
            resp.write(file, "binary");
            resp.end();
        }
    });
}
```

For good measure, here is the html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>First steps</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/upload" enctype ="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="upload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the console it gives me an error that fs.unlink and fs.rename are missing a callback, however it does go to the show request handler but doesn't display the image.
Is there a simpler way to do things? Thx

Answer (score 3):

After quite a few trial and errors, I found out what prevented the code to work, there are two conditions:

- all the `"/tmp/test.png"` links need to be replaced with `"./tmp/test.png"` to make them relative to current project folder
- there needs to be a folder inside the current project named `/tmp`, it doesn't need to include anything, but it needs to be there, Windows can not create it, if it isn't. I might need to add some lines of code to check whether it exists before uploading and renaming a file to this folder.

Actually, does anyone know why in the address bar still shows `http://localhost:8888/upload` ? I thought it would indicate `http://localhost:8888/show` ??!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and in my case it was because files were being uploaded to a temporary location on my C: drive, but the project files were on my D: drive, and copying across drives was creating a problem for fs.rename(). I hardwired the destination to the C: drive and then it worked fine.